# What is the quickest way to isolate the source of an error amongst a list of potential sources?

Tags: debugging, testing, puzzle

What is the quickest way to isolate the source of an error amongst an ordered list of potential sources?  For example, given a list of column mappings, and one of those column mappings is incorrect, what debugging technique would lead you to most quickly identify which mapping is invalid?  (By most quickly, I mean, which approach would require the fewest compilation, load, and run cycles?)

Assume that whatever error message the database or database driver generates does not identify the name of the errant column.  Sound familiar?

**Hint:**

The technique is similar to that which you might use to answer the question, "What number am I thinking of between 1 and 1000?", but with the fewest guesses.

Comment: There's no silver bullet. Just get your hands dirty.

Comment: There really is no best way. But generally, if you're having a hard time isolating errors, it is because the error messages aren't detailed enough -- as you say. Sometimes you can wrap things around those errors to include the relevant details.

Comment: Come on guys, think harder! There is a specific approach that will lead you to find the problem more quickly than say, eliminating each column one at a time.

Comment: In case you're curious, the motivation for this question came from a problem that I had to solve today that involved, yes, isolating a column mapping that was causing a Hibernate query to fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use interpolation in some cases. I've used this successfully to isolate a bad record.

Comment: What do you mean by interpolation?

Comment: Its a math method for quickly finding the problem. We used it in the slide rule days. Cut the data set in half, if it doesn't error  then the problem is inthe other half, so cut that in half, if it doesn't error it is in the next half. If it does error, cut the sample in half until you are down to the record it is erroring on.  You can very quickly find the record that is causing the problem in very little time. for column mappings remove half the columns and see if you still get a mapping error, etc.

Comment: Exactly!  You got it!  I think another term for interpolation is "bisection", which is the term that Git uses to name its command "git bisect" (http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-bisect.html) which uses binary search to find a change that introduced a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds familiar, but I hate to be the one to tell you that there is no "quick" way of isolating the sources of errors. I know from my own experience that you want to be absolutely sure you've found the correct source of error before you go about resolving it, and this requires plenty of testing and tracing.

Answer (score 0):

Keep adding more and more diagnostic information until I either isolate the issue, or can't add anymore. If it's my code vs. external code, I will go crazy with trace statements until I isolate the critical bit of code if I otherwise don't know where the issue is. On Windows, the SysInternals suite is my friend... especially the debug viewer. That will show any trace statements from anything running on the system that is emitting trace.

If I truly cannot get more specific information from the error source, then I will go into experimental mode... testing one small change at a time. This works best if you know you have a case that succeeds and a case that does not.

Trivial example: If I have row X that won't be inserted into the database, but I know row Y will, I will then take row Y and change one field at a time and keep inserting until row Y's values = row X's value.

If you really are stumped at where the issue is coming from, time to dust off your Google-fu skills. Someone has probably run into the same problem and posted a question to a forum somewhere. Of course, that's what SO is for too.

You're the human... be more stubborn than the computer!